# Ubuntu: Issue in removing package ultimate-download-manager2

Tags: package-management, uninstall, delete

I installed program from ubuntu software center, the program is called ultimated media downloader 2. However, after that I tried to remove it but I could not find it using dpkg -l, or apt-get remove/purge, any idea how can I remove it.

Another issue is that the software center does not show the uninstall button, and keeps it as install. When I click on it I receive the message that the package is already installed.

I am using ubuntu 17.10

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is a snap package, and can be removed by

```
snap remove ultimate-media-downloader2
```